# Facebook Graph API numbers do not match my Fan Page numbers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I just have an issue with the page fans count. The website shows around 1M of fans but when I extracted them from the API the numbers is close to 930K.

The way I request using this:

```
name:"page_fans",
period:"lifetime"
```

I open a Bug, but they say is due ti privacy settings issue but there isn't any documentation about it. Do you have any idea why the difference? if there is any work around? or what privacy issues are affecting the api request?

Thanks,
J.

Comment: You get what you get - live with it. Facebook is not going to lift any privacy restrictions just for you, so you can get a slightly different number.

Comment: For example users that have turned all API access/apps of in their settings, are generally “invisible” to all 3rd-party apps.

Comment: Thank for the answer. The problem is that I can live with it but not the owner of a brand or of Facebook site. Also they don't say it before your building your reports.